# PySNMP - default location of the compiled MIBs

Tags: pysnmp

1. I configured the compiler where to look for asn1 MIBs as follows:

   ```
   compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/usr/share/snmp/mibs'])
   ```
2. Then used getCmd() as:

   ```
   errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
       getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
              CommunityData('private', mpModel=0),
              UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.56.20', '161')),
              ContextData(),
              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('VLAN-MIB','InterfaceMode',3))))
   ```
3. I find VLAN-MIB.py in `$HOME/.pysnmp/mibs` and everything worked fine.

But I wanted to modify the asn1 MIBs location to my local folder. Say:

```
/home/krish/mibs
```

I tried it in 2 different ways:

1. This:

   ```
   compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/home/krish/mibs'])`
   ```
2. This:

   ```
   errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
       getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
              CommunityData('private', mpModel=0),
              UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.56.20', '161')),
              ContextData(),
              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('VLAN-MIB','InterfaceMode',3).addAsn1MibSource('/home/krish/mibs')))
   )
   ```

Either way, I am getting error which says that VLAN-MIB could not be found.

But if I compile it myself offline and place the VLAN-MIB.py file in the specified directory as:

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
           CommunityData('private', mpModel=0),
           UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.56.20', '161')),
           ContextData(),
           ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('VLAN-MIB','InterfaceMode',3).addMibSource('/home/krish/mibs')))
)
```

it worked fine.

So my question is where the compiled MIBs (.py) are placed after PySMI is automatically parses the asn1 MIBs? I did not find them in default location `$HOME/.pysnmp/mibs` in the above case.

and how do I tell pysnmp/pysmi where to keep the auto-generated .py file.

and I don't want to use `addMibSource()` in every get/set calls. `addMibCompiler()` worked fine only for the /usr/share/snmp/mibs, not for the user directories.

Wondering what I am missing here. Appreciate help.

Comment: Please, specify the pysnmp version you are using?

Comment: pysnmp version 4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

My guesses are:

- It is that ASN.1 MIB could not be found, not its compiled counterpart `VLAN-MIB.py`
- It is not that ASN.1 `VLAN-MIB` could not be found, but some other ASN.1 MIB on which `VLAN-MIB` is dependent

What exactly pysnmp error says?

Since you work with ASN.1 MIBs, e.g. not pysmi pre-compiled ones, you should use `.addMibCompiler` or `.addAsn1MibSource` for setting up search path.

Despite its name, `.addMibCompiler`/`.addAsn1MibSource` do not *add* a path but *set* a new one(s) for given `MibBuilder` instance. Thus you should always specify all sources of MIBs your application might need for MIBs you refer to and for MIBs imported by those you refer to (and that goes recursively).

You can pass the `destination` keyword parameter to `.addMibCompiler`/`.addAsn1MibSource` functions to alter compiled MIBs location.

Having said that I'd propose to try:

```
addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/home/krish/mibs', '/usr/share/snmp/mibs'])
```

or

```
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('VLAN-MIB','InterfaceMode',3).addAsn1MibSource('/home/krish/mibs', '/usr/share/snmp/mibs')))
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick to just `/home/krish/mibs`, try copying all required MIBs into that directory. Import errors from pysnmp report missing dependencies.

Finally, there is a large collection of various MIBs on-line you could configure pysnmp to automatically download and use:

```
addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/@mib@'], destination='/home/krish/mibs')
```

Comment: You guess is right about " some other ASN.1 MIB on which VLAN-MIB is dependent".  Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.