# PySNMP - MIB fails to compile

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, snmp, pysnmp

I am using pysnmp to grab data from the lldpRemTable. I was able to get the specific values I wanted, but I need to the use MIB to get what each value is. (e.g. know that Ethernet1/1 is lldpRemPortId) Originally, I was getting an 'pysnmp.smi.error.MibNotFoundError' error for LLDP-MIB, but I changed the filepath to be an absolute path and now I get one for SNMPv2-TC. What is strange is that I am using the similar code for cdpCacheTable and it works without a hitch (even before changing to an absolute path). I thought that this may be because the CISCO-CDP-MIB is already compiled with pysnmp (or at least on my machine), but I noticed that if I don't compile it here (i.e. comment out lines 1 and 3) then the object labels are not correct.

Here is the working cdpCacheTable code:

```
    mib_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/mibs'
    mib_builder = builder.MibBuilder()
    compiler.addMibCompiler(mib_builder, sources=[mib_file])
    mib_builder.loadModules('CISCO-CDP-MIB')
    mib_view = view.MibViewController(mib_builder)
```

Here is the problematic lldpRemTable code:

```
    mib_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/mibs'
    mib_builder = builder.MibBuilder()
    compiler.addMibCompiler(mib_builder, sources=[mib_file])
    mib_builder.loadModules('LLDP-MIB')
    mib_view = view.MibViewController(mib_builder)
```

My CISCO-CDP-MIB and LLDP-MIB files are stored in the ./mibs directory as indicated above.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840456/pysnmp-default-location-of-the-compiled-mibs) and a response seemed to corroborate my thought that when specifying sources it does not consider pysnmp's defaults. So I edited my code to the following:

```
    mib_file = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/mibs'
    mib_builder = builder.MibBuilder()
    compiler.addMibCompiler(mib_builder, sources=[mib_file, os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.local /lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs'], destination=os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysnmp/smi/mibs')
    mib_builder.loadModules('LLDP-MIB')
    mib_view = view.MibViewController(mib_builder)
```

Which still produced a similar MibNotFoundError. After using `debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('all'))` it seems that it was still not finding the other MIBs needed. I also tried manually adding all the ones it kept saying it required to my /mibs folder from https://github.com/lextudio/mibs.pysnmp.com and the same issue kept happening. (Would likely have to have a ton of mibs in my folder for it to work.)

I'd like to do something as simple as I did for the cdpCacheTable, but I have not been able to find a solution yet.

EDIT: The creator says "Generally, to compile a MIB you have to have all the MIBs it imports (and the MIBs they import and so forth). In other words, you have to have all the MIBs in the dependency chain in uncompiled form." on https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/229 so maybe I do have to pull in every single MIB into my /mibs folder? This does not seem the most ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my edit, it seems that looking through all of the imports in my MIBs and adding them to my /mibs folder has solved the issue. (If this is the only solution, I guess I will just have to get comfortable with having this many MIBs in my repository.)

Comment: "it seems that looking through all of the imports in my MIBs and adding them to my /mibs folder has solved the issue" is exactly the answer given in https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/issues/229. All SNMP libraries (for whatever language) follow this approach.